# My h2 working, but i cant connect inside of h2-console

Tags: java, spring, database, h2

**Yoo coder**, have one issue with **h2-console**.When i created some entitys on start,my h2 worked and i could open my h2-console and saw there tables ,but after some time i want connect again and doesn't work now.Meanwhile i added some lines and classes,but idk why doesn't work my h2-console,cause i don't touch application properties.
After lick on conect or testconect i got this ***error***

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Mar 14 19:12:33 CET 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
```

My github project: https://github.com/Wynnyy/bookingdoctor-project.git

[image]

logs

```
2022-03-14 19:12:16.222  INFO 23108 --- [           main] s.w.b.BookingdoctorApplication           : Starting BookingdoctorApplication using Java 17.0.2 on DESKTOP-K3O8I67 with PID 23108 (C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\bookingdoctor\target\classes started by Wynny in C:\Users\Patrik Severín\IdeaProjects\bookingdoctor)
2022-03-14 19:12:16.224  INFO 23108 --- [           main] s.w.b.BookingdoctorApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-14 19:12:16.928  INFO 23108 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-14 19:12:16.986  INFO 23108 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 47 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-03-14 19:12:17.670  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-03-14 19:12:17.682  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-14 19:12:17.682  INFO 23108 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
2022-03-14 19:12:17.780  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-14 19:12:17.780  INFO 23108 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1503 ms
2022-03-14 19:12:17.829  INFO 23108 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-03-14 19:12:18.068  INFO 23108 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-03-14 19:12:18.080  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:wynny'
2022-03-14 19:12:18.277  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-03-14 19:12:18.331  INFO 23108 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
2022-03-14 19:12:18.497  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-03-14 19:12:18.627  INFO 23108 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-03-14 19:12:19.225  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-03-14 19:12:19.232  INFO 23108 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-03-14 19:12:19.540  WARN 23108 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-03-14 19:12:19.708  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will not secure any request
2022-03-14 19:12:20.112  INFO 23108 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-03-14 19:12:20.211  INFO 23108 --- [           main] s.w.b.BookingdoctorApplication           : Started BookingdoctorApplication in 4.362 seconds (JVM running for 4.745)
2022-03-14 19:12:24.415  INFO 23108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-03-14 19:12:24.415  INFO 23108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-03-14 19:12:24.417  INFO 23108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

Comment: problem is in my spring security,but idk why security damaged my h2console

Answer (score 2):

By default, spring-security will protect each and every end-point - So, for /error you need to manually configure like the following -

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity auth) {
        auth.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll() // permit-all for /error  page
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For future reference:

In Spring Boot 3.0 / Spring Security 6.0 `http.antMatcher()` is not longer available and was replaced with `http.securityMatcher()`.

So Subham's answer would look like that:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .csrf().disable()
                .securityMatcher("/error/**")
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much